# Is it necessary to close database connection in node js with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, node.js, database-connection

I am using `npm-mssql` with nodejs. Can anybody please confirm me if I need to close the database connection manually or is it automatically closed?

I have got some info [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#connection) but not clear to me. Please help...

Comment: If using pooling option, it will handle for you automatically.

Answer (score 3):

It would be closed automatically when the garbage collector works!

Though it's a good practice to close any db connection manually after you are done with it, db connection is a heavy resource so closing it to dispose the occupied resources is always a good idea and best practice.

Not only for db connections, but that should be the case for any heavy resource process, like any other I/O operation.